# WIZ how to skip custom action from executing from parameters while installing msi through command line.?

Tags: wix

i have sucessfully installed my msi in silent mode using the following command. msiexec /i mysetup.msi /qn. Also, i have a custom action in my installsequence which is a gui for some configuration. And i dont want that gui appears while installing in silent/command line...

Answer (score 0):

If running in *completely* silent mode, the "UILevel" property will be equal to 2. Check out [this reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/uilevel) for the different levels of UI.

To apply it to your WIX project, in the Sequence you're running the Custom Action, add a condition for the property so your EXE isn't run if that is true.  Something like this:

```
<Custom Action="CA_GUIConfig" After="SetUILEVEL">Not UILevel="2"</Custom>
```

It may be that the property you need to use in your condition is CLIENTUILEVEL, but it's UILevel that's being checked in my custom code (it's been 10 years since I wrote it, so I'm not exactly clear now). Between either of those 2 properties, I think you'll get it.